# NodeJS / Koa Passthrough buffer not flushing when using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

Having the following issue when trying to pipe a response from Koa.js like so:

This example works as expected (sends the string 'ping' every second back to the client):

```
const delay = time => new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,time));

const testFn = async (context, next) => {
      context.request.socket.setTimeout(0);
      context.req.socket.setNoDelay(true);
      context.req.socket.setKeepAlive(true);

      context.set({
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
      });

      //Create response stream
      const responseStream = new PassThrough();

      context.status = 200;
      context.body = responseStream;
      
      setInterval(() => { responseStream.write('ping') }, 1000);

      await next();
}
```

This example does not work (flushes the stream only at the end of the request):

```
const delay = time => new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,time));

const testFn = async (context, next) => {
      context.request.socket.setTimeout(0);
      context.req.socket.setNoDelay(true);
      context.req.socket.setKeepAlive(true);

      context.set({
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
      });

      //Create response stream
      const responseStream = new PassThrough();

      context.status = 200;
      context.body = responseStream;
      
      for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        responseStream.write('ping')
        await delay(1000);
      }

      await next();
}
```

What I need it to do is to push the messages as they are sent (basically need to implement a live log and a loading bar for a long-running api call).

Any idea what is going on here and how I may fix it?

Thanks!